# Исправьте проблему с итерированием

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задание: 
Прочитать строку (например: ghgh:4 6:ghgr help:us) и вывести список строк, в котором лежат значения справа от двоеточия. Нельзя использовать dict, list, set

Код:

```
b = input()
c = b.split()
d = (str(c)).split(':')
print(d)
```

Или:

```
a = [j for i, j in enumerate(input().split())]
```

Comment: Какой ожидаемый результат для `ghgh:4 6:ghgr help:us`? `4 6 us`?

Comment: Добавьте пример что на входе и что хотите на выходе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой ручной перебор в цикле:

```
text = 'ghgh:4 6:ghgr help:us'
start = -1

for i in range(len(text)):
    c = text[i]
    if c == ':':
        start = i + 1
        continue

    if c == ' ':
        print(text[start: i])

    if i == len(text) - 1:
        print(text[start: i + 1])

# 4
# ghgr
# us
```

---

Сделать разделение по пробелам, у получившихся частей сделать разбиение по `:`, вывод результата в каждой строке

Код:

```
text = 'ghgh:4 6:ghgr help:us'

print(*(x.split(':', maxsplit=1)[1] for x in text.split()), sep='\n')
# 4
# ghgr
# us
```

---

Через регулярные выражения:

```
import re

text = 'ghgh:4 6:ghgr help:us'
print(*(m.group(1) for m in re.finditer(r':(\w+)', text)), sep='\n')
# 4
# ghgr
# us
```

Comment: Нельзя использовать dict, list, set :) У Вас split делает list :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, мб, там имеется ввиду явное использование built-in функций (dict, list, set), а не типы

Answer (score 0):

Код для новичков:

```
text = "ghgh:4 6:ghgr help:us"
right_from_colon  = False
res = ""
for letter in text:
    if letter == ":":
        right_from_colon = True
        continue
    elif letter == " ":
        right_from_colon = False
        res += letter
    if right_from_colon:
        res += letter
print(res)
```